# How to oil fan with no holes?

Tags: fan

The fan of my graphic card has turned very noisy. I read some tutorials and it seems that with a drop of oil I could resurrect it.

The problem is, that it seems to be sealed. There are no holes in the spinning part, and in the rear-static part, there are three small holes, but not a central one for the axis, where I am supposed to apply the oil

[image: Rear part of fan]

So, question: is it possible to oil it? or I don't have any other option but buying a new one.

Comment: Can you access the other side of the fan? Meaning, with it remaining as the picture shows, between the underside of the fan and metal casing... May be with a straw or similar you could add a little drop there?

Comment: Are they not screws in the fan?

Comment: Most of this stuff it is very hard to get to the bearings, and if the bearings have died on these small things the oil only gives them some small time. If you have nothing to lose, carefully create a hole right there on what is shown as the top under what was the sticker in the dead center. then drop the oil down there, it will give you a few months of life.  Myself i would rather put a 80mm thin fan stuffed in instead, wire up the 2 pins and use it like that, because the small ones do not come back to life.

Comment: I think I have to mention using a high speed rotary craft tool like a dremmel to make the hole. With a high speed tool you do not use downward pressure , it uses the speed instead, so you dont go flying past the plastic when creating the hole, into the bearing or what might be the pcb (printed curcuit board).

Comment: Nope, the other side does not have any kind of hole under the sticker. I tried to pull the spining part but no way it would go out. Through the gap between the two parts I can't reach the bearing, just the cable coils. Making a hole looks like overkill and could damage some coil. I think I'm going to order one in ebay, and stay with the noise until the new one comes. Thank you very much for your time, all of you.

Answer (score 2):

Mine looked as if there was no hole, just a solid piece of plastic.  But when we poked it with a screwdriver, we realised that it was a rubber bung which pulled out easily!  My fan is absolutely silent now!